# Filter objects by custom attribute

Tags: django, django-models

I try to pass filter parameter from form to view in order to filter objects in Django by custom "index":

```
profile_list = Profile.objects.filter(
    company=request.user.company,
)
if request.method == 'POST':
    search_key = request.POST.get('skey')
    search_query = request.POST.get('squery', None)
    profile_list = profile_list.filter(
        search_key=search_query
    )
```

But I can't use this code, I get:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'search_key' into field.
```

Which is normal, there is no search_key attribute. How should I format this to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value of the variable `search_key` to be used as the keyword, you'll want to throw it in a dict and use keyword expansion via `**`

```
profile_list = profile_list.filter(
   **{search_key:search_query}
)



profile_list = profile_list.filter(
   **{'%s__contains' % search_key:search_query}
)
```

Comment: What is I want to do "contains" query instead of exact comparison?

Comment: Then modify your search key to contain whatever you need. In your case.. search_key needs to evaluate to "something__contains"

Answer (score 1):

You can create dict and pass that to filter as

```
qdict = { search_key: search_query }
profile_list = profile_list.filter( **qdict)
```